# driver.navigate.refresh not working as expected with selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Please follow the code below:

```
driver.get "https://example.com/"
driver.find_element(:class, "button").submit
driver.navigate.refresh
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:name => "username") }
```

I wrote the code keeping in my mind that till the page which contains `element : username` comes, continue the previous page to refresh. But it seems my code not meeting that requirement. Thus script throwing error as below "

***Error***

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdr
iver/common/wait.rb:57:in `until': timed out after 10 seconds (Unable to locate
element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"})} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::
TimeOutError)
```

Any good idea to meet my requirement,please?

Thanks,

Comment: please share few more lines of code.

Comment: please make me clear if i am wrong. After you reached the `element : username` you going to refresh the previous page.

Comment: My code is wrong. until the `element : username` page is coming I need to keep refreshing the previous page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not come across a built-in way to do this in selenium-webdriver, so I would do the following:

```
#Submit your first page
driver.get "https://example.com/"
driver.find_element(:class, "button").submit

#Refresh page until your element appears
end_time = Time.now + 10 #seconds
begin
    element = driver.find_element(:name => "username")
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    if Time.now < end_time
        driver.navigate.refresh
        retry
    end
end
```

Basically this is attempting to find the element. If it is not found, catches the exception, refreshes the page and retries again. This is repeated until the time limit hsa been reached.

Comment: OMG! What a solution you have given. This is the exactly the one,I was looking for. Thank you very much:)

Comment: what `retry` statement would do here?

Comment: It means to rerun the code between the `begin` and `rescue`. So in this case, it is saying to retry finding the element after the page refresh.

Comment: Could you please help me in the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569044/confusion-with-ruby-file-class-related-path-methods#comment20336013_14569044)? - this is very basic. I am getting confused in my example what I mentioned in the description. Could you give me a lesson on that?