# Confusion with Ruby File class related PATH methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am getting confused with the utility of the `File Class` methods as below:

```
 1. File::absolute_path
 2. File::realdirpath
 3. File::realpath
 4. File::expand_path
```

***What I tried below:***

```
irb(main):001:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Users/Matt"
irb(main):002:0> Dir.chdir('D:\VB Script\excel_ie_wsh')
=> 0
irb(main):003:0> Dir.pwd
=> "D:/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh"
irb(main):005:0> File.realdirpath('\VB Script\excel_ie_wsh')
=> "/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh"
irb(main):006:0> File.realpath('\VB Script\excel_ie_wsh')
=> "/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh"
irb(main):007:0> File.absolute_path('\VB Script\excel_ie_wsh')
=> "D:/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh"
irb(main):008:0> File.realpath('readme.txt')
=> "D:/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh/readme.txt"
irb(main):009:0> File.realdirpath('readme.txt')
=> "D:/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh/readme.txt"
irb(main):012:0> File.absolute_path('readme.txt')
=> "D:/VB Script/excel_ie_wsh/readme.txt"
irb(main):013:0>
```

*Questions:*

1. Why `File.realdirpath` and `File.realpath` produces the same output?
2. How `File.realpath` differs from `File.absolute_path`?
3. How does `absolute_path(file_nam)` differ from `absolute_path(file_name[, dir_string] )`?
4. How does `realdirpath(pathname)` differ from `realdirpath(pathname [,
   dir_string])` ?

Comment: You can't show any code you've written as you try to understand this?

Comment: Yes I tried. But that's why the confusion arose in my mind.

Comment: Still, show you made an attempt, instead of throwing out the question and showing no effort. Explain why it is confusing.

Comment: @theTinMan I have updated my description. Now could you teach me?

Comment: RTFM: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html

Comment: @zetetic Yes, I read that. but confused with my code testing. Have you seen last three lines of my code output? Why they have come as same output?

Comment: Read the documentation for those methods, and ask yourself, what is the difference between "relative" and "absolute" paths. If you don't know, find out, as it's basic file-system information. Do you understand what "`~`" is in a path? If not, find out. What does "`..`" do in a path? Those are things that affect the output of those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why File.realdirpath and File.realpath produces the same output?**

As per the ruby-doc, the only difference between these two methods is whether or not the last component of the pathname must exist. `realdirpath` does not care, where as `realpath` will throw an exception.

For example, when getting the path of a file that does not exist:

```
irb(main):001:0> File.realpath('nonexistent.file')
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - H:/nonexistent.file
        from (irb):1:in `realpath'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):002:0> File.realdirpath('nonexistent.file')
=> "H:/nonexistent.file"
```

**How File.realpath differs from File.absolute_path?**

I am not on a UNIX system to test this, but my guess is that the only difference is when the path starts the tilde (ie ~). In UNIX, the tilde represents the home directory. I assume the difference between the two methods is whether or not it expands the home directory or not.

If you are on windows, it should not matter (ie there is no home directory shortcut).

**How does realdirpath(pathname) differ from realdirpath(pathname [, dir_string]) ?**

The ruby-doc states "If dir_string is given, it is used as a base directory for interpreting relative pathname instead of the current directory." In other words, dir_string can be specified to override the starting point.

For example, let us assume that:

1. You are running irb from the root of your H: drive (ie this is your current directory)
2. You have a sub-folder named 'Folder' (ie H:\Folder)

Then you can see the difference:

```
H:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> File.realdirpath('test.txt')
=> "H:/test.txt"

irb(main):002:0> File.realdirpath('test.txt', './Expense')
=> "H:/Expense/test.txt"
```

You can see that the second statement locates the file with respect to the directory stated in dir_string.

**How does absolute_path(file_nam) differ from absolute_path(file_name[, dir_string] )?**

This is the same as the previous question.

Comment: Thank you very much @justin Ko! Could you please teach me outside of `SO`. I love basic programming knowledge. And you can explain those very smoothly,previously I had seen. So I will be proud if I get some lessons from you - Honestly speaking :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not to answer your question, it's to help preserve your sanity as you work with languages like Ruby, Perl, and probably Python, on a Windows box.

Don't waste your time writing your paths using back-slashes. Instead, join the *nix-type OSes and use forward slashes in your code. This will make it easier to move files from a desktop environment to a networking/hosting environment since the big-iron on the internet and enterprises is usually a *nix system.

The [IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) says:

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename “/gumby/ruby/test.rb” will be opened as “\gumby\ruby\test.rb”. When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes:

```
"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"
```

> Our examples here will use the Unix-style forward slashes; File::SEPARATOR can be used to get the platform-specific separator character.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand the basic of such methods with my example code? Which might help me to understand the logic?